# Failed to contact master at 172.x.x.x

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I'am trying to connect my **pioneer LX Robot with my own system in which ROS Kinetic is installed for SLAM(in Ubuntu 16.04)** via wifi,but after runnig this command

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.x.x.x:11311
```

when i run

```
rosrun rosaria RosAria
```

every time i got the following error..

```
xyz@xyz-Desktop:~/catkin_ws$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.16.21.202:11311
xyz@xyz-Desktop:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosaria RosAria
[ERROR] [1494496662.614976996]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [172.16.21.202:11311].  Retrying...
Connnecting to robot using TCP connection to localhost:8101...
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
ArSerialConnection::open: Could not open serial port '/dev/ttyUSB0' | ErrorFromOSNum: 2 ErrorFromOSString: No such file or directory
Could not connect, because open on the device connection failed.
Failed to connect to robot.
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261502/failed-to-contact-master-at-172.x.x.x/) by [Robita](https://answers.ros.org/users/30171/robita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-11**:
Could you please update your question to clearly indicate which command you run on which computer / robot? Right now this is rather ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a wild guest, given the lack of info, but:

You also need to export either ROS_HOSTNAME or ROS_IP variables:

```
export ROS_IP=172.x.x.x
```

ROS_HOSTNAME requires, that the provided hostname is resolvable, so ROS_IP, is your choice for simple setup.

This might be helpfull [ROS Network Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup)

---

Originally posted by [spooner-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/29765/spooner-dev/) with karma: 151 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1